# How to make IValueConverter return text with different fontsizes, superscripts and/or subscripts

Tags: c#, wpf

Can anyone please let me know how I could make a Converter return text with varying font-sizes, so that the bound textblock can display it? If this is not possible with a TextBlock, I can use alternative element as well.

Here is the code that I have right now, this obviously doesn't work

In my XAML file:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource LabelFormatConerter}}"/>
```

In my XAML.cs file:

```
public class LabelFormatConerter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
        Run runLargeFont = new Run();
        runLargeFont.FontSize = 18;
        runLargeFont.Text = "Larger Font Text";
        tb.Inlines.Add(runBase);

        Run runSmallFont = new Run();
        runSmallFont.FontSize = 8;
        runSmallFont.BaselineAlignment = BaselineAlignment.Superscript;
        runSmallFont.Text = "Smaller Font Text";
        tb.Inlines.Add(runSmallFont);

        return tb.Text;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you actually converting `value` with this converter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="Calibri">
        <Run>Normal Text</Run>
        <Run Typography.Variants="Superscript">Test</Run>
        <Run Typography.Variants="Subscript">7</Run>
</TextBlock>
```

Not all fonts support super\subscripts, so I had to specify it explictly.

What will be your input? Two/three separate values, or one value that you need to split into a normal value, superscript and subscript?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your answer in combination with Victor Hurdugaci's got what I was looking for. My input was only one value that had to be split into a superscript and regular text, as in 10ⁿ.

Answer (score 1):

This might be possible to do with a TextBlock but I don't know how. Your converter returns a collection of `Run` objects, while the `Text` property expects a string.

An alternative is to user an items control:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource LabelFormatConerter}}" />
```

and return

```
tb.Inlines
```

from your converter. (ideally you just create just a collection inside your converter, not a new TextBlock)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your answer in combination with @Fayilt's got what I was looking for. My input was only one value that had to be split into a superscript and regular text, as in 10ⁿ.

Answer (score 1):

A converter is not the right tool for this job - this is what `ContentTemplate` is there for. Simply use a `ContentControl`, bind the data to the `Content` property and display the data however your want to in your `ContentTemplate`:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Person}">
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run FontSize="18" Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                <Run FontSize="8"  Text="{Binding LastName}" />
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```